# utf8 strings/ boost trim?

Tags: boost, unicode-string

I am trying to process utf8 strings. I have the string "比 ", which seems like a pretty reasonable string to me; it's encoded as e6 af 94 e2 80 83 or bi3(e6 af 94) unicode_space (e2 80 83).

locales are all set to suggest that we are not in kansas any more and have left for the earth locale (utf8)...

boost::trim really hates this and squinting at the implementation it seems to be rooted in Kansas; ie it assumes that a "character" is a fixed number of bits. Dear friends; have I understood this correctly?

If I have, do you have any suggestions for a cross platform C++ utf-8 aware string library?

Can I really not use boost? jeez!

I know that I could switch to 16 bit character strings... but I really do not want to do that....

Any thoughts much appreciated,

jolyon

Answer (score 0):

```
void utf8trim(std::string& aStringUtf8)
{
    // remove any ascii whitespace
    boost::trim(aStringUtf8);

    // leave kansas. convert to a 32 bit string...
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> cvt;
    std::u32string utf32 = cvt.from_bytes(aStringUtf8);

    // and remove any esoteric whitespace; see:-
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

    ::boost::algorithm::trim_if(utf32, boost::is_any_of(U"\x2000\x2001\x2002\x2003\x2004\x2005\x2006\x2007\x2009\x200A\x2028\x2029\x202f\x205f\x3000"));

    // now convert this back to utf8
    aStringUtf8  = cvt.to_bytes(utf32);
}
```

Comment: really? surely  a better way?!